# Triangulation - third coordinate of triangle

Tags: triangulation

I would like to ask : I have coordinates of two towers on the beach : A[x,y] B[x,y] . I know distane between them. My task is now to find out coordinate of the ship on sea.I also know both angles that towers makes with the ship. I assume that it will be like to calculate third coordinate of triangle, but I dont know how. Can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: Use sine rule: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines. This gives the distance of the  ship from one tower.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are allowed to use as math tools.

One way could be:

Knowing a point on a line and its angel will allow you to determine the line equation through a tower location. You will get for each tower a line equation. These two lines intersect at the ship location - solve the system of two equations with two unknowns and the result will be the (x, y) of the ship.